# Graph Theory proof: Let G be a planar graph that doesn't contain K3...

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

So I'm trying to solve this practice exam question,

> Let $G$ be a planar graph with at least two edges and does not contain $K_{3}$ as a subgraph.  Prove that $|E|\leq 2|V|-4$.

Now I started doing this by induction, but it seems to me like the base-case is a counter-example.  If I draw two edges that connect two vertices, this seems to be planar since the edges don't intersect and it doesn't contain $K_{3}$ because it only has two nodes.  Yet in this case, $2\not\leq 2(2)-4$.

Am I doing something wrong?  The edges don't have to be straight do they?  I thought the shape of the edges was unimportant.

Comment: The key word is "graph".  There are other varieties of graphs, but with no modifier specified you should assume "simple graph", meaning no double edges and no loops.  Your example has a double edge.

Comment: @Erick Wong, Thank you for the help.  So by saying that one should assume no double edges, would that also mean that you couldn't have many directed edges coming out of a single node?  Or does that simply mean that, if an edge goes from v to w, then there cannot also be an edge from w to v?

Comment: Again, without modifier one should silently assume that graph means undirected graph.

Comment: Oh, then i misunderstood what Wong was saying--i thought by "double edge" he meant two directed edges, equivalent to an undirected edge. So i should assume undirected edges and no two nodes are connected by two edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty standard, just combine the Euler formula with counting edges by faces.

By Euler formula

$$V-E+F=2$$

The proof below, assumes that there exists at least two faces, you need to check separately the case $F=1$.

Now, lets count the edges by faces. Since each edge belongs to exactly 2 faces (here is where we need  $F \geq 2$) our count is **exactly**  $2E$.

The graph has $F=E-V+2$ faces, and each face has at least $4$ edges (because no triangles), out count is at least
$$4F=4(E-V+2) \,.$$

Therefore
$$2E =\mbox{our count} \geq 4E-4V+8 \,.$$

This is exactly your inequality.

**P.S.** The proof assumes that the graph is simple, if the graph is not simple then loops lead to faces with only one edge and multiedges to faces with 2 edges.

Answer (score 1):

We first prove the following lemma.

> If $G$ is a connected simple graph, $|E(G)| \geq 2$. Then, every region of has length at least $3$.

*Proof*. Indeed, the only possible nontrivial closed walk of length at most $2$ in a simple graph traces a single edge in both directions. Such a walk can form a boundary of a region only if the whole graph consists of $2$ vertices and $1$ edge, proving the lemma.

Now, we want to show that given a planar graph $G$ with $|E(G)| \geq 2$ which does not contain $K_3$ as a subgraph, we have $|E(G)| \leq 2|V(G)| - 4$.

We may assume that $G$ is connected by adding an extra edge. Note that if we do not make any assumption on whether $G$ contains $K_3$ or not, we have the relation
$$2|E(G)| = \sum_{\text{regions $r$}} \mathrm{Length}(r) \geq 3\mathrm{Reg}(G)$$
by the Lemma, so that $\mathrm{Reg}(G) \leq \tfrac{2}{3}|E(G)|$. By Euler, we also have
$$2 = |V(G)| - |E(G)| + \mathrm{Reg}(G) \leq |V(G)| - \frac{|E(G)|}{3}.$$

Hence, $6 \leq 3|V(G)| - |E(G)|$. Now, if $K_3 < G$, then $G$ has not region of length $3$, so we have that $\tfrac{1}{2}|E(G)| \geq \mathrm{Reg}(G)$. It follows that $|E(G)| \leq 2|V(G)| - 4$, as desired.